# How to create folders in android 6.0 app drawer on an LG phone?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, lg, file-management

I cannot find how to  create folders in my new android 6 device's app drawer (the screen that comes after I press [this](http://www.beginandroid.com/images/appdraw140.jpg) button to show all the apps). Is this option disabled?

In android 4 if I remember correctly I had to press and hold an application icon and the 'create folder' option would appear.

How do I create folders in android 6.0?

Comment: Which launcher app are you using?

Comment: I don't think I am using any launcher app. I just press the button in this picture http://www.beginandroid.com/images/appdraw140.jpg

Comment: Your screenshot shows your device's launcher :) There's always one pre-installed. So in your case it would help to know what device you're using in order to tell what launcher it is.

Comment: It is a screenshot from a website! not from my device! Can you tell me how I can find what launcher I have ? My phone is an LG G4 and I suppose I have whatever it had for default

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I think I found the answer to my own question.

You can create folders if you are in default android 6.0 app drawer this way:

press and hold the right hardware button (the square one) while being in the app drawer screen, then select 'edit/uninstall apps' and drag an app onto another one. This creates a folder with these 2 apps inside it!

Answer (score 1):

To create folders in the app drawer android 6.0.1 you open the app drawer and at the top right tap EDIT then drag and drop apps on top of each other. That's it.

My device is the Samsung On5 (MetroPCS)

Answer (score 0):

On your Apps menu drag the app upwards, an option will appear on the left to create folder. Name the folder and it will appear on your home screen. You can also put files into folders too.

Comment: What phone does this answer relate to?

Answer (score 0):

If you drag the apps towards each other, you can get series of options in which you can find create folder option.